Abrir URL dinámica con Php y PODs
Deseo ejecutar el enlace de un campo dinámico creado con Pods (tipo web), para ello uso este código:
<?php 
$link = get_field('url_dinamico');
if( $link ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>"></a>
<?php endif; ?>

Para insertarlo lo hago a través de un shortcode que me genera "WPCode" [wpcode id="2281"], lo pongo en un widget de ícono usando Elementor (campo enlace / etiqueta dinámica / Shortcode).
Sin embargo, cuando abro la página y doy click en dicho botón, me lleva a la misma URL del sitio en el que me encuentro en ese momento. Sin embargo, si modifico el código de esta manera:
<?php 
$link = get_field('url_dinamico');
if( $link ): ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>">Botón de prueba</a>
<?php endif; ?>

Me genera correctamente un botón que me abre la web ingresada en el campo dinámico en una nueva pestaña.
¿Qué podría modificar del código anterior para que pueda insertarlo como enlace en el widget que deseo?

Para aquellos que tuvieron el mismo problema, utilice este código php usando "WPCode"
<a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_field('tu_campo') ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_attr( get_field('tu_campo') ); ?></a>

Especifiquen el nombre de su campo personalizado donde dice 'tu_campo'.
Saludos.

tu mismo te has contestado. en tu modificación.
SI vemos tu codigo
<?php 
$link = get_field('url_dinamico');
if( $link ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>"></a>
<?php endif; ?>

no hay nada dentro del enlace para que el enlace funcione. Estou hablando de esto.
   <a href=""> AQUI NO HAY NADA </a>  

no hay nada dentro del enlace para que este funcione como enlace. En cambio en tu modificación .
   <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>">Botón de prueba</a>

Dentro del enlace existe un texto. Boton de prueba  que hace que el enlace funcione.
Acuérdate que la etiqueta link necesita (algún elemento o etiqueta ) entre la apertura y el cierre que permita al enlace funcionar.
Saludos

Hola Hugo, gracias por darte un tiempo en dar un comentario. Entiendo lo que dices, sin embargo, lo que busco es ejecutar un enlace dinámico, alimentado por un campo creado usando el plugin PODs, es por ello que en mi primer código no colocaba el texto botón de prueba. ¿Me ayudarías editando el código para que si se pueda abrir el enlace dinámico ingresado en el campo? yo quiero insertar este enlace en un widget, por ello no necesito un texto para que funcione.
